# How to use jquery to get to previous li

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following html:

```
<li>
    <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Presentation Name</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="not-allowed" id="survey_kind">Survey Length</a>
</li>
```

and here is the jquery:

```
var yolo = $('.not-allowed').first();
yolo.removeClass("not-allowed");
yolo.prev("li").addClass("active");
```

The first two lines of javascript are working.  For some reason, i can't get the last line to work.  I'm trying to have the second li tag have the class active, but the class is just not being added anywhere.

Comment: Tried, but that didnt work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have a look at this with the example. I think this answers your question: https://api.jquery.com/prev/

**Markup**

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$( "li.third-item" ).prev().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

I made a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/nq6efza9/

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer got down voted.  It was exactly what I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: @Philip7899 - No, you stated in your question "I'm trying to have the second li tag have the class active". Your HTML is different from the HTML in this question, and .prev() would not work based on your code and your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There is no previous element for that link. You want to get  the *parent* of the link:

```
yolo.parent().addClass("active");
```

Ref: [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/844fwyge/)**

<sub>Note that you could also use `.closest('li')` instead of `.parent()`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You want `parent()` not `prev()`.

Comment: Why won't prev work?  i read the docs for prev and it looks like what i wrote should work?

Comment: Your element is nested _inside_ the `li`. `prev` refers to adjacent elements; `parent` refers to, well, the parent.

Comment: because there is no prev sibling, you have on <a> isnide the li element

Answer (score 0):

.prev() queries only the siblings of the element, and .not-allowed has none. In order to use .prev() you'd need to call .parent() to get the list item element the anchor is within:

```
yolo.parent().prev("li").addClass("active");
```

Edit: I'm an idiot

Comment: _"I'm trying to have the *second li tag* have the class active"_